# find the last added sheet (vba)?

Tags: excel, vba

How to get the last sheet created in excel ?
I used GetSheets.Last, and it work but he found me the last sheet what it is in queued, it’s right, but if my last sheet doesn’t follow the order of the queued for example it is in the middle, the function GetSheets.Last doesn’t work.
Exist some function where the robot can found or understand which sheet has been created for last ?

Thanks 
regards

Comment: As far as I know worksheets don't carry such metadata - you can't know which sheet was added first or last, nor sort them by the order they were created in. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Is your code creating the sheets? If so, you could use `CustomProperties` to store some `Timestamp` metadata. ...that wouldn't help with sheets not created by the macro though.

Comment: You can use `Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)`.  This will give you the index number of the highest numbered sheet, which should have been the last one created.

Comment: @DarrellH until `Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)` is moved, yes.

Comment: OK, since nobody else has mentioned it, I'll bite and ask why you need to know the order that worksheets were added. It sounds like you're trying to treat the worksheets themselves as data, which indicates a design problem.

Comment: AFAIK the sheetID in the .zip file of your xlsm is numbered consecutively (workbook.xml). I don't know if there's a possibillity to read from it in the same/open file.

Answer (score 1):

You might try accessing the worksheet's codename. This is suffixed by a sequential number .

It should be mentioned that if you a) delete a worksheet and b) close then reopen the workbook and c) add a new worksheet, the new worksheet might be assigned an old codename making this method unreliable.

Although it is not as common as changing a worksheet's name, a worksheet's codename can be altered manually as well.

```
function getLastAddedWorksheet()

    dim i as long, mx as long, ws as worksheet

    on error resume next

    for i = 1 to worksheets.count
        if mx < val(mid(worksheets(i).codename, 6)) then
             set ws = worksheets(i)
             mx = val(mid(ws.codename, 6))
        end if
    next i

    getLastAddedWorksheet = ws.name

    on error goto 0

end function
```

Comment: IMO it's kind of very sad that worksheet code names aren't more systematically altered.

Answer (score 1):

When you programmatically add a worksheet, the `Worksheets.Add` function yields a reference to the just-added `Worksheet` object: that is normally how VBA code gets a handle on the "last created worksheet".

```
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Set newSheet = book.Worksheets.Add
'use newSheet object to refer to the newly added worksheet.
```

---

If we're talking about *manually* added worksheets, things need to get more ...involved.

Assuming you need to track *all* sheets added to *all* workbooks, you could have an Excel add-in that handles application-wide events like so:

```
Private WithEvents app As Excel.Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set app = ThisWorkbook.Application
End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookNewSheet(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Not TypeOf Sh Is Excel.Worksheet Then Exit Sub

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sh

    ws.CustomProperties.Add "DateCreated", Now

End Sub
```

Excluding `Application.EnableEvents = False`, I'm not 100% convinced that handler would run in every possible case that can create a worksheet, but I guess it's better than nothing.

You can then have a function that gets you the `DateCreated` custom property given a `Worksheet` instance:

```
Public Function GetDateCreated(ByVal ws As worksheet) As Date
    Dim p As CustomProperty
    For Each p In ws.CustomProperties
        If p.Name = "DateCreated" Then
            GetDateCreated = p.Value
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    GetDateCreated = 0 ' unknown
End Function
```

And then all that's left to do is to write a procedure that can sort the sheets based on their associated `DateCreated` custom property value.

Comment: There is a ThisWorkbook.Workbook_NewSheet event sub as well.

Comment: @user10970498 yes, but that would only pick up new sheets in `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: I guess it depends on whether the 'latest workbook' requirement is more important for one workbook on many computers or many workbooks on one computer.  Excel add-ins are not always the easiest to distribute but an XLSM/XLSB carries its subs with itself.

Comment: Granted... TBH I agree with [Comintern here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54406234/find-the-last-added-sheet-vba/54406605?noredirect=1#comment95623979_54406234), this is very likely not something the OP *actually* needs to be doing - but it's a fun problem to try & solve though :)  ...OP doesn't specify whether it's about *a* workbook, or about *any* workbook.. I went with the broader option